# Leaflet.markercluster - how to count all markers in a markerClusterGroup?

Tags: leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

I am using [Leaflet.markercluster](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster).

This is my code, basd upon the various related questions:

```
    // Takes an L.markerClusterGroup as input parameter
    Self.GetNumMarkersInClusterGroup = function(clusterGroup)
    {
        Self.map.eachLayer(function (layer) {
            if (layer.getChildCount) {
// somehow need to check here for our desired cluter group

                console.log('Cluster group has ' + layer._childClusters.length + 'layers')        ;
                console.log('With a total of ' + layer._childCount + ' markers');  
                }
        });
    }       // GetNumMarkersInClusterGroup()
```

but, `layer.getChildCount` is undefined :-(  What am I doing wrongly?

---

Related questions:

- [iterate over cluster in markerCluster : leaflet](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/129429/iterate-over-cluster-in-markercluster-leaflet)
- [Count elements in MarkerCluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58707554/count-elements-in-markercluster)
- [Getting number of clusters and its markers with Leaflet?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/264545/getting-number-of-clusters-and-its-markers-with-leaflet)
- [Getting the childcount in leaflet markercluster](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/233535/getting-the-childcount-in-leaflet-markercluster)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is true that there may be some confusion in how to use Leaflet.markercluster plugin:

- There is the overall MarkerClusterGroup (MCG) object, i.e. what you get when calling `L.markerClusterGroup()`
- the Cluster Markers, which are what the MCG displays on the map when your individual Markers are clustered together
- the individual Markers that you add into an MCG

If your `clusterGroup` is actually an MCG, then you can simply use the fact that it extends Leaflet standard Feature Group and Layer Group, and in particular it has a [`getLayers()` method](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#layergroup-getlayers):

> Returns an array of all the layers added to the group.

So if you want the *total* number of Markers in your MCG, you can do e.g. `clusterGroup.getLayers().length`

For completeness, the MCG also has the methods referred to in the Leaflet.markercluster documentation as ["group methods"](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster#group-methods)

And the [`getChildCount()` method](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster#customising-the-clustered-markers) (and `getAllChildMarkers()`) is for the Cluster Markers, which are e.g. what you get when using `"clusterclick"` event and the like.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and the explanation. I can see now that I should not be using `getAllChildMarkers()` when not handling  an event. I just want to get than number of markers in an MCG, e.g just after having parsed data & add markers to multiple groups.