# Assigning ID to marker and adding and removing from cluster using leaf.js

Tags: javascript, google-maps-markers, leaflet.markercluster

i am new to leaflet and clusters but I have managed to get some custom markers on a map with leaflet.js maps and cluster.

All is good apart from I cant seem to work out how to remove a marker as it does not seem to assign an ID number or anything. I have tried to use this sort of thing to add an ID but not getting anywhere and hence why I have not attempted to remove the marker.

```
var user_id = '101';

 var marker[user_id] = L.marker(new L.LatLng(a[0], a[1]), {
 icon: client,
 title: title
 });
```

I have the data in this format :-

```
var addressPoints = [
[52.4134975, -1.5131260, "101", "YES"],
[52.4904975, -1.5151260, "102", "NO"],
[52.4734975, -1.5171260, "103", "BUSY"],
[52.4194975, -1.5181260, "104", "NO"],
[52.4264975, -1.5130460, "105", "YES"],
[52.4284975, -1.5191210, "106", "YES"],
[52.4014975, -1.5191949, "107", "BUSY"],
[52.4299975, -1.5110060, "108", "NO"]
]
```

I use this code to loop through them and add to the map with custom marker, it works good but if I want to remove or change the CSS on one I cant locate it.

```
var map = L.mapbox.map('map')
      .setView([52.450439, -1.729660], 14)
      .addLayer(L.mapbox.styleLayer('mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11'));

    var markers = new L.MarkerClusterGroup();



    for (var i = 0; i < addressPoints.length; i++) {
            var a = addressPoints[i];
            var online_status = a[3];
            var user_id = a[2];
            var imgts = a[2];
            var title = a[2];

// Add online users //  

    if  (online_status === "YES") {
    console.log('online');
                var client = L.divIcon({
                className: 'location-pin',          
                html: '<img id"operatorimg" src="img/'+imgts+'.jpg"><div class="pin online"><div class="pulse"></div>',
                iconSize: [30, 30],
                iconAnchor: [18, 30]
        });
        
        var marker = L.marker(new L.LatLng(a[0], a[1]), {
            icon: client,
            title: title
        });
    
    }

        marker.bindPopup(title);
        markers.addLayer(marker);
    }

    map.addLayer(markers);
```

I have tried to assign some sort of ID when looping but its not having it? Am i taking the wrong approach? Any help is appreciated and sorry if I have not put this up correctly, I have just joined.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leaflet markers are classes, so one thing you can try is to add a property to the class and find the marker by that property. For instance, if you have a marker and the data for the marker contains a name, you can add a `name` property to the marker. Then, you need to cycle through the layers in the `markerClusterGroup` to find the marker you want to remove. According to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65746946/15165070), `L.markerClusterGroup` extends Leaflet's [`layerGroup`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#layergroup), so you can use the [`eachLayer` method](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#map-eachlayer) to iterate each layer in the group. Then, you can find the desired marker by the property you assigned earlier and use the [`removeFrom` method](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#layer-removefrom) to remove it from the map. Here's an example using Leaflet's `layerGroup`:

```js
import L from 'leaflet';

var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([51.505, -0.09], 12);

var tile = {
  base: 'https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
  attr: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
};
var tileLayer = L.tileLayer(tile.base, {
  attribution: tile.attr,
  maxZoom: 18,
  tileSize: 512,
  zoomOffset: -1,
}).addTo(mymap);

// Create a group for the layers:
var markerLayer = L.layerGroup().addTo(mymap);

var pointsForMarker = [
  { name: 'Center Of London', lat: 51.5, lng: -0.09 },
  { name: 'Big Ben', lat: 51.5007, lng: -0.1246 },
  { name: 'Buckingham Palace', lat: 51.5014, lng: -0.1419 },
];

var originalMarkerStyles = `
  background-color: black;
  width: 3em;
  height: 3em;
  display: block;
  left: -1.5em;
  top: -1.5em;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 3rem 3rem 0;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  border: 1px solid #FFFFFF`;

var myIcon = L.divIcon({
  className: 'custom-icon',
  iconAnchor: [0, 24],
  labelAnchor: [-6, 0],
  popupAnchor: [0, -36],
  html: `<span style="${originalMarkerStyles}"></span>`,
});

// Add points to the map:
pointsForMarker.forEach((point) => {
  var marker = L.marker(point, { icon: myIcon }).addTo(markerLayer);
  marker.bindPopup(`NAME: ${point.name}`).openPopup();
  // Add a 'name' property to the marker class:
  marker.name = point.name;
});

var dismissBtn = document.querySelector('#dismissBtn');
dismissBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  // When button clicked, user prompted to enter name for marker to dismiss:
  var markerToDismiss = prompt(
    'Enter name of marker to dismiss:',
    'buckingham palace'
  );
  // Iterate through each layer (marker) in layerGroup:
  markerLayer.eachLayer((layer) => {
    if (markerToDismiss) {
      // If the name property on the marker matches the name entered in the prompt:
      if (
        layer.name.trim().toLowerCase() === markerToDismiss.trim().toLowerCase()
      ) {
        // Remove the marker:
        layer.removeFrom(markerLayer);
      }
    }
  });
});

// To change the style of a custom Icon:
var colorBtn = document.querySelector('#colorBtn');
colorBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  var markerToChange = prompt('Enter name to change marker color:', 'big ben');
  markerLayer.eachLayer((layer) => {
    if (markerToChange) {
      if (
        layer.name.trim().toLowerCase() === markerToChange.trim().toLowerCase()
      ) {
        var newStyle = `
          background-color: red;
          width: 5em;
          height: 5em;
          display: block;
          left: -1.5em;
          top: -1.5em;
          position: relative;
          border-radius: 3rem 3rem 0;
          transform: rotate(45deg);
          border: 1px solid #FFFFFF`;
        var newIcon = L.divIcon({
          className: 'custom-icon',
          iconAnchor: [0, 24],
          labelAnchor: [-6, 0],
          popupAnchor: [0, -36],
          html: `<span style="${newStyle}"></span>`,
        });
        // Use the L.marker.setIcon to set an icon with the style changes:
        layer.setIcon(newIcon);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

[Here is a demo set up on StackBlitz for you to play with](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-pbia82?file=index.js)

Comment: Mate your a diamond, got it working now with custom marker. Could I also use this technique for altering the CSS of named marker? Thanks again

Comment: @KidfromCov I wasn't able to change the CSS directly, but I was able to use the marker method [`setIcon`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#marker-seticon) to set it to a new icon with the desired style changes. I've updated the answer and the sandbox to reflect this. I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to jharris711 for the above code, I implemented it like so and works a treat with custom marker.

```
pointsForMarker.forEach((point) => {

            var client = L.divIcon({
                className: 'location-pin',          
                html: '<img id"operatorimg" src="img/'+point.name+'.jpg"><div class="pin"></div>',
                iconSize: [30, 30],
                iconAnchor: [18, 30]
        });
        var marker = L.marker ([point.lat, point.lng], {
            icon: client
        });
  markerLayer.addLayer(marker);
  marker.name = point.name;
  //alert(marker.name);
});

markerLayer.eachLayer((layer) => {
    // console.log(layer);
    
    var markerToDismiss = "LILLY";
    
    if (markerToDismiss) {
      // If the name property on the marker matches the name entered in the prompt:
      if (

        layer.name.trim().toLowerCase() === markerToDismiss.trim().toLowerCase()
      ) {
        // Remove the marker:
        layer.removeFrom(markerLayer);
      }
    }
  });
```

Thanks again